Best way to calculate velocity, acceleration and jerk with different temporal resolutions
I already posted my question on the Physics StackExchange and was told to come and ask the question here.
I have 3D motion tracking data of people, that I am using for my thesis. I am trying to find relationships between the kinematics of the body of speakers, and the acoustic measures of their speech (e.g. speech envelope, pitch, intensity...).
Before performing analyses such as coherence or mutual information, I downsample my data from 200 Hz to 50 Hz (mostly to speed up computation time).
On the following graphs, you'll see the original data (sampled at 200 Hz) in blue, and the linearly-resampled data in orange (at 50 Hz).
Here is the x, y, and z position across time for one of my markers (the right hand of one speaker). The two curves are on top of each other:

So far so good. Then, I calculate the distance traveled, i.e. the Euclidian distance between a point a times $t_1$ and $t_2$:
$$d_{t_{2}} = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}$$
Because my temporal resolution is not the same, then I get the following graph. The orange curve is roughly four times more ample than the blue, which is logical as the temporal resolution is 4 times lower:

Now, to standardize this, I use velocities: because I divide the distance traveled between two timestamps by the time elapsed, the curves overlay again. We can see, thanks to this, that the downsampling removed some fast movements - which is fine because the motion capture comes with some jitter:
$$v_{t_{2}} = \frac{d_{t_{2}}}{t_2-t_1}$$

Now, this is fine to study the variations of velocity with the acoustic measures mentioned earlier. However, the literature mentions some relationships with the acceleration phases of movement - I am then also interested in studying the acceleration, and the jerk to see the variations in acceleration.
I use this formula to calculate the acceleration:
$$a_{t_{3}} = \left(\frac{v_{t_{3}} - v_{t_{2}}}{t_3-t_2}\right)$$
The problem is that, this time, due to my differences in temporal resolution, I get differences in acceleration amplitudes (I am plotting the absolute values on the graph below):

This might be a problem for the future analyses - especially if I need to analyses the jerk, which should reduce the amplitudes by a factor 16 compared to the original 200 Hz data.
My question is the following: How can I preserve the relative amplitude despite the downsampling?
Thanks for your answers :)

Remember back in calculus, the derivative can be defined as
$$\frac d {dt} f(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac {f(t + \Delta t) - f(t)}{\Delta t} \tag 1$$
or
$$\frac d {dt} f(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac {f(t) - f(t - \Delta t)}{\Delta t} \tag 2$$
(or other things).
You're "differentiating" by finding $f(T_s n) - f(T_s (n - 1))$, without dividing by $T_s$.
So, the most basic answer is to divide by your sample time ($0.02 \mathrm s$ if you're sampling at $50 \mathrm{Hz}$) each time you take the derivative.
Note that there are better ways of doing what you're doing -- you can combine the smoothing with taking the derivative, and with some work you can take the statistics of the motion capture into account to find the optimal approximations for velocity, acceleration, and jerk.
But if you just scale by $\frac 1 {T_s}$ each time you take a numerical derivative, you'll be a lot closer.

Hi and thanks a lot for your answer :) Dividing by the sample time will already solve a big chunk of my issues.
Now, I am interested about what you say here: "you can combine the smoothing with taking the derivative". Do you mean I should take the derivative before downsampling?
Thank you!

Do a web search on "smoothed estimate of derivative" or "smoothed derivative".  If you run into problems understanding, ask a new question here.
